# How to layer a ribbon under points?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to put a ribbon under my points, but when I try, I run into an error. Here's a (too) minimal reproducible example; the `x` in `d1` is a factor because I'm plotting boxplots as well, I took them out to make it minimal, but that actually made matters confusing!

This version works just fine, but the ribbon covers up my points!

```
d1 <- data.frame(x=factor(c("a", "b"), y=c(1.3, 1.5))
d2 <- data.frame(x=c(0,3), g=1, lwr=1, upr=2)
ggplot(d1) + aes(x,y) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=x,ymin=lwr,ymax=upr), fill="gray80", data=d2, inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

But when I simply swap the order of the layers, I get an error!

```
ggplot(d1) + aes(x,y) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=x,ymin=lwr,ymax=upr), fill="gray80", data=d2, inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  geom_point()
## Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

I could simply use alpha to blend it, but I want the color of my ribbon to match other figures.

```
ggplot(d1) + aes(x,y) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=x,ymin=lwr,ymax=upr), alpha=0.2, data=d2, inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

Comment: Do you need the `x` in `d1` to be a factor?  Why not convert to numeric if the underlying data are numbers?

Comment: simple hack appears to be to run geom_point twice. Once before and once after geom_ribbon

Comment: I think this is one of the things that using `geom_blank` is for.  You make a blank graph based on the global aesthetics to make everything discrete prior to adding the other layers.

Comment: Hi all, I oversimplified my example, it appears; the `x` in d1 is a factor because I'm also plotting boxplots, one for each level of `x`.

Comment: Decided to change the numeric values to character to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have here stems from the fact you have different types of variables for the `x` column in `d1`(a factor) and `d2` (numeric). You can force ggplot to plot a discrete scale using `scale_x_discrete()`:

```
ggplot(d1) + aes(x,y) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=x,ymin=lwr,ymax=upr), fill="gray80", data=d2, inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you are probably better off correcting the dataset before plotting, as I am not sure why you want to overlay factors and integer variables?

```
d1 <- data.frame(x=c(1:2), y=c(1.3, 1.5))
d2 <- data.frame(x=c(0,3), g=1, lwr=1, upr=2)
ggplot(d1) + aes(x,y) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=x,ymin=lwr,ymax=upr), fill="gray80", data=d2, inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Both of these are good options; I'll use the first, but to use the second I could override the ticks and labels to put my factor names back on.